# How to prove $\sum\limits_{a\in A_{0}}a^i=\sum\limits_{b\in B_{0}}b^i$

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

This following set identity arises in an olympiad problem. For the case $i=k+1$ I can't prove it.

> Let $A,B$ be two disjoint subsets of $R~~(|A|=|B|=n)$ such that
>   $$\sum_{a\in A}a^i=\sum_{b\in A}b^i \ \ (i=0,1,2,\cdots,k)$$
>   define
>   $$A_{0}=A\bigcup (B+x)~~ B_{0}=B\bigcup (A+x)(x\in R)$$

Show that: for all $i=0,1,2,\cdots,k+1$,we have
$$\sum_{a\in A_{0}}a^i=\sum_{b\in B_{0}}b^i$$
where $A_{0},B_{0}$ is multiset.

(A multiset is a set-like collection of elements in which order is ignored, but repetition of elements is allowed and multiplicity of elements is significant.  For example, multisets $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{2, 1, 3\}$ are equivalent, but $\{1, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3\}$ differ.)

for example $A=\{-2,2\},B=\{-1,1\},k=1,x=1$hypothesis hold,and
$$A_{0}=\{-2,2,0,2\},B_{0}=\{-1,1,-1,3\}$$
since
$$-2+2+0+2=-1+1-1+3=2$$
$$(-2)^2+2^2+0^2+2^2=(-1)^2+1^2+(-1)^2+3^2=12$$

WLOG Let $A=\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}\}.~~B=\{b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}\}$
It seem for $i=k+1$ use [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).But I can't prove it

Comment: Some hypothesis must be missing. Taking $A=\{-1,1\}$, $B=\{-2,2\}$, $k=1$ and $x=1$, hypothesis hold, but conclusions not.

Comment: Hello,$A_{0},B_{0}$ is  multiset

Answer (score 1):

For a multiset $X$ with elements from $R$, let
$$\Sigma^k X:=\sum_{x\in X}x^k$$
where sum is taken with multiplicities in order to simplify notation - note that $\Sigma^0 X=|X|$ by convention. Then we can easily see that:

1. For multisets $X$ and $Y$ with elements from $R$, $\Sigma^i(X\cup Y)=\Sigma^iX+\Sigma^iY$.
2. For any $t\in R$ and any finite multiset $X$ with elements from $R$, $$\Sigma^r(X+t)=\sum_{i=0}^r\,\binom{r}{i}t^{r-i}\Sigma^iX$$ by applying the Binomial Theorem.

In this way, we obtain that
$$\Sigma^iA_0=\Sigma^iA+\sum_{j=0}^i\,\binom{i}{j}x^{i-j}\Sigma^jB$$
and that
$$\Sigma^iB_0=\Sigma^iB+\sum_{j=0}^i\,\binom{i}{j}x^{i-j}\Sigma^jA$$
which by arranging terms give
$$\Sigma^iA_0=\Sigma^iA+\Sigma^iB+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\,\binom{i}{j}x^{i-j}\Sigma^jB$$
and
$$\Sigma^iB_0=\Sigma^iA+\Sigma^iB+\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\,\binom{i}{j}x^{i-j}\Sigma^jA\text{.}$$
In this way, we have that whenever
$$\Sigma^iA=\Sigma^iB$$
for $i\in\{0,1,\ldots,k\}$, then
$$\Sigma^iA_0=\Sigma^iB_0$$
for $i\in\{0,1,\ldots,k+1\}$ as in order to guarantee the equality
$$\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\,\binom{r}{j}x^{r-j}\Sigma^jB=\sum_{j=0}^{r-1}\,\binom{r}{j}x^{r-j}\Sigma^jA$$
for some $r$ we just need that $\Sigma^jA=\Sigma^jB$ for all $j<r$. This is the desired statement.